# How to build Phonegap plugin for native contact picker (Android)?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How do I even start doing this? I can't find any good documentation to really guide me through this process. I am willing to do the work and try to read and understand, but I almost don't know how to approach this at all.

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ContactView

Comment: That plugin does not work, I made another post about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621105/phonegap-android-contact-picker-plugin-updating-a-plugin).