# Android - Contact picker in Phonegap 2.6.0

Tags: android, cordova, contacts

I'm trying to pick a contact from the native contacts app in Android and return the phone number into my app in Phonegap.
I did it in iOS easily with no plugin needed by doing:

```
function contactChooser(){
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.fields = ["displayName", "name", "emails", "phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.chooseContact( onSuccess, options);
}

function onSuccess(id, contact){
    var nombre = contact['name']['formatted'];
    var telefono = contact['phoneNumbers'][0];

    console.log(id);
    console.log(nombre);
    console.log(telefono);
}
```

But when I run that code in Android, the console shouts:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'chooseContact'
```

In the other hand, I tried to use the Phonegap plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ContactView) but it's 2 years old, and not currently working.

Does anyone know how to simply pick a contact from the native contactbook and get it's phone number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ContactView plugin works in 2.6 replacing **this.ctx.startActivityForResult**, I answered the same question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621105/phonegap-android-contact-picker-plugin-updating-a-plugin/17012111#17012111)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cordova documentation you should use the [ContactField object](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#ContactField) to get the phone of a contact. This API is supported on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Yes, but that applies if I already know what contact to get the data from, but what I want to do is a contact picker, so the user can choose one and then retrieve that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that contactChooser (**undocumented**) is only available for ios platforms.I cant find such method in cordova.js on **android but IOS**.